# How do I get my dog back on The Sims FreePlay app?

Tags: the-sims-freeplay

I lost my dog after trying to relocate it. I don't know what happened. Is there a way to get it back or get another one?

Answer (score 2):

You either did one of three things:

1. Accidentally click the "Put up for Adoption" which basically deletes the pet.

   Solution: If its deleted, you will have to buy another one. Check each household to make sure.
2. Relocate the dog to a different house than you intended to.

   Solution: Again, check each household.
3. Relocate the dog to a house, and the dog is just hiding somewhere. Especially, in the larger lots and in more complex houses, the dog is usually hidden from view.

   Solution: Navigate the camera in the household. If you want an easy check, buy a dog bowl(Food at 10,000 Simoleans or Water at 8,000 Simoleans), have a sim fill it if not already filled, and do the action "Call Over". If the dog is there, he/she should come.

Answer (score 0):

If you are relocating a dog to the teen idol mansion, the dog, for some reason, shows up in the island created in the center of the swimming pool. You can rescue the dog from this trap by removing one of the pools so there is a way to walk out from the island.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe,you put him a other household (if you unlocked the front beach homes you will MAY find him/her) it may been a glich you know sims freeplay have SO many GLICHES so I suggest to turn off your game then click back on the app see if it worked.Or get some that has the dog do an action like call over to eat!

Hope this helped!And I hope you find your dog!

Answer (score -4):

After a certain rank, and after buying the Pet Shop, you get a Pets tab in the shop. There, you can buy more dogs or even other pets like bunnies, but they cost those green things (sorry, I forget what they're called.)

Actually, I have no idea what could have happened to your dog, probably a glitch, but if you want, you can just buy more. Hope this helps.